# stack trace error in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I have installed skeleton application and working sample test skeleton application.after i have to add module structure in zend skeleton application its showing error.My module Name "Album".

Module.php

```
<?php
//testzf2/module/Album/Module.php
namespace Album;

class Album
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' =>
            array('namespaces' =>
                array(__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
?>
```

module.config.php

```
<?php
//testzf2/module/Album/config/module.config.php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',   // <----- Module Controller
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',  // <---- url format module/action/id
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',  // <--- Defined as the module controller
                        'action'     => 'index',                   // <---- Default action
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Albumcontroller.php

```
<?php
//testzf2/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumComtroller.php
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array('valueA'=>555
                    ,'propertyB'=>888);
    }
}
?>
```

I am receiving error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Application) could not be initialized.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:195 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(169): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(96): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Application') #2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventMana in D:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 195
```

Comment: any body have any idea?please post your idea here. thanks in advancne

Answer (score 0):

The error messages says:

> Module (Application) could not be initialized.

So it hate nothing to do with your Album module!
I think your config/application.config.php has wrong paths and/or your Module.php/config.module.php is not correct in Application

Answer (score 0):

Your `Module.php` signature doesn't respecting [PSR autoloading standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and ZF2's [Module Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.loader.module-autoloader.html#zend-loader-module-autoloader) couldn't initialize your module.

Try to change classname `Album` from

```
<?php
namespace Album;

class Album
{
```

to

```
<?php
namespace Album;

class Module
{
```

This should work.